# Lead Report is not displaying data

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports, custom-reports

I have two fields in my Standard Salesforce lead report, One is text and other one is date field. When I ran my report it is observed that, the report is showing all the leads info with text and date field only if the text field is not blank.

i.e if the text field value is blank on the lead then the date field value is also showing blank in the report where as in the actual lead the date field has value.
Both the fields are custom fields and I am running the report as a system admin.
Any thoughts?

Comment: IMO this could happen only in the case if Date field is actually a date formula field and has some sort of dependency on  text field.

Comment: date field is of type date and there is no dependency.

Comment: The issue is resolved by creating a new custom report type and report for Lead. I was using the Salesforce OOB report type.